# Why putting inline function def in other header file which include the header file where the inline function declaration in is a link error?

Tags: c++, inline, one-definition-rule

I have two headers.

```
// header1.h
class A
{
public:
    void f();
};

// header2.h
#include "header1.h"
inline void A::f()
{
    std::cout << "Yahoo.";
}

// test1.cpp
#include "header1.h"
int main() { A a; a.f(); return 0; }

// test2.cpp
#include "header2.h"
void ff() { /* do nothing */ }
```

I got a link error on MSVC 2013.
I only got one translation unit, so I think that maybe "ODR" is not the reason?

Now I have test2.cpp to include header2.h. So I think that linker can find header2.h now.
But still link error, why?

Comment: The rule is "An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used." `A::f()` is not defined in `test.cpp` since it doesn't include `header2.h`.

Comment: And how do you expect the compiler to even know anything about the existence of `header2.h`??? It is not included or mentioned anywhere in your code. With the very same degree of success, you could have placed your function definition into an email message and sent it to Zanzibar.

Comment: @AndreyT I add a file include header2.h, still error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you do it with inline function. In the `test.cpp` file, how would the compiler even *know* that the function `A::f` is marked `inline`?

If you want an inline member function, you have to define it in the same header file, or include the header file where it's defined.

So solution one: `#include "header2.h"` instead of `"header1.h"`.

Solution two: Define the function inline inside the class:

```
class A
{
public:
    void f() { ... }
};
```

Solution three: Define the function after the class but in the same header file:

```
class A { ... };

inline void A::f() { ... }
```

Comment: So compiler think that A::f() is undefined?

Comment: @Huang-zh The *compiler* don't know, or even care. The *linker* needs to know that all symbols are defined, and since no [translation unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (i.e. source file) defines the `A::f` function you will get an undefined symbol error from the linker.

Comment: I add a file to include header2.h, got one translation unit defining A::f(maybe?).But still error...

Comment: @Huang-zh Yes, because inline functions are defined only in the translation unit they are defined in. Include the header file in the main source file instead. Or define it in the main header file.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler doesn't know where to find `A::f()` because you've never told it where to look. You need to `#include "header2.h"` in test.cpp. Either that, or move the definition of A::f() into `header1.h`.